# How to limit floats generated by Quickcheck to a range?

Tags: testing, rust

I would like to generate random floats for [Quickcheck](https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck) that are limited to a certain range such as 0.0 to 1.0 for testing functions working on probabilities. I would like to be able to do something where this would be successful:

```
quickcheck! {        
    fn prop(x: f64, y: f64) -> bool {
        assert!(x <= 1.0);
        assert!(y <= 1.0);

        (x * y < x) && (x * y < y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new type that represents your desired range, then implement [`quickcheck::Arbitrary`](https://docs.rs/quickcheck/0.4.2/quickcheck/trait.Arbitrary.html) for it:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quickcheck;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Probability(f64);

impl quickcheck::Arbitrary for Probability {
    fn arbitrary<G: quickcheck::Gen>(g: &mut G) -> Self {
        Probability(g.gen_range(0.0, 1.0))
    }
}

quickcheck! {
    fn prop(x: Probability, y: Probability) -> bool {
        let x = x.0;
        let y = y.0;

        assert!(x <= 1.0);
        assert!(y <= 1.0);

        (x * y < x) && (x * y < y)
    }
}
```

`Arbitrary` is passed a type that implements [`quickcheck::Gen`](https://docs.rs/quickcheck/0.4.2/quickcheck/trait.Gen.html), which is a light wrapper on top of [`rand::Rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.3.15/rand/trait.Rng.html).

Note that `Rng::gen_range` has an **exclusive upper bound**, so this example isn't exactly what you want, but it shows the process.

Comment: Please update this answer, as `Gen::gen_range` [is now private](https://docs.rs/quickcheck/latest/src/quickcheck/arbitrary.rs.html#65-78).

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `Arbitrary` for a new type is still probably the best way to do this, but `gen_range()` is now a private method, so you can't use that. [As pointed out by the crate's author](https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck/issues/267#issuecomment-763068292), you can use the modulus to restrict values to a range.

You can even do this without creating a new type (note that I'm using newer Rust syntax and the `quickcheck_macros` crate):

```
#[quickcheck]
fn prop(x: f64, y: f64) -> bool {
    let x = x.abs() % 1.0;
    let y = y.abs() % 1.0;
    assert!(x <= 1.0);
    assert!(y <= 1.0);

    (x * y < x) && (x * y < y)
}
```

However, when it fails, it will report the original values of `x` and `y`, not the modified ones. So for better test failure reporting, you should use this in code similar to @Shepmaster's:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Probability(f64);

impl quickcheck::Arbitrary for Probability {
    fn arbitrary(g: &mut quickcheck::Gen) -> Self {
        Probability(f64::arbitrary(g).abs() % 1.0)
    }
}

#[quickcheck]
fn prop2(x: Probability, y: Probability) {
    let x = x.0;
    let y = y.0;

    // ...
}
```

Of course, once you do all this, you'll notice your code failing for two reasons:

1. Since `x` and `y` could be exactly equal to `1.0`, that means it's not a strict inequality. The true comparison should actually be `(x * y <= x) && (x * y <= y)`.
2. `f64::arbitrary` can return NaN. If you want to skip NaNs, you could do that by either:

   - Returning `quickcheck::TestCase` from `prop()`, and returning `TestCase::discard()` if it sees a NaN input, or:
   - Looping inside `Probability::arbitrary` until you generate a non-NaN number.